# Drag and drop ranking function in Laravel form

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel, laravel-8

I am making a survey form and I was to have the user drag and drop for a ranking system. I have the attached code but the tiles don't move when I try to drag the across. Is there any way to fix this or an alternative? When I try to drag an item over, it instead highlights the text.

```
survey.blade.php

  <script>
    $(function(){
  
  item_height=$(".item").outerHeight(true);
  height=(item_height+2)*($(".item").length+1);
  $(".source-container,.destination-container").height(height);
  
    

  $(".source .item").draggable({
    revert:"invalid",
    start:function(){
      
      $(this).data("index",$(this).parent().index());
      
    }
  });
  
  $(".destination").droppable({
      drop:function(evern,ui){
          if($(this).has(".item").length){
            if(ui.draggable.parent().hasClass("source")){
                index=ui.draggable.data("index");
                ui.draggable.css({left:"0",top:"0"}).appendTo($(".source").eq(index));
            }
            else{
             ui.draggable.css({left:"0",top:"0"}).appendTo($(this));
              index=ui.draggable.data("index");
              $(this).find(".item").eq(0).appendTo($(".destination").eq(index))
            }
          }
        else{
          ui.draggable.css({left:"1px",top:"1px"});
          ui.draggable.appendTo($(this));
          $(".destination").removeClass("ui-droppable-active");
        }
      }
  });
  
  $(".source").droppable({
    accept: function(draggable) {
        return $(this).find("*").length == 0;
    },
   drop:function(event,ui){
     ui.draggable.css({left:"0",top:"0"}).appendTo($(this))
   }
  })
  
  
  
  
})
  </script>

<h3>Drag and drop items on right for ranking</h3>
                <div class='container'>
                  
                  
                <div class="source-container">
                 <div class='source'>
                   <div class='item'>
                    <p>Item 1</p>
                   </div>
                 </div>
                  
                  <div class='source'>
                   <div class='item'>
                    <p>Item 2</p>
                   </div>
                 </div>
                  
                  <div class='source'>
                   <div class='item'>
                    <p>Item 3</p>
                   </div>
                 </div>
                       
                 </div>
                 
                </div>
                  <div class='move-back'>
                  </div>
                <div class='destination-container'>
                  <div class="destination" id="dest1">
                    <span>1</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="destination" id="dest2">
                    <span>2</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="destination" id="dest3">
                    <span>3</span>
                  </div>

                </div>
```

For reference, I added 3 items to rank but I would like to add more.

Comment: Nothing in your browser's DevConsole? Is jquery loaded? Is jqueryUI loaded? (assuming this is jquery)

Comment: @brombeer just html, css and js